# FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance showing warning but compiles successfully

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

When I write code about firebase analytics like `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance()` I get a warning message:

> Missing permissions required by FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I didn't found anything about this by googling.

I also tried cleaning and rebuilding my project. Restarting Android studio. Nothing worked.

What's the issue?

**Edit:** Permissions are there. I can see those in the merged manifest. But still gives the error.

[image]

Comment: You can ignore the warning. `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `WAKE_LOCK` is Normal Permissions and not required to ask on Run-Time. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)

Comment: @AnkurJain But they should be in the manifest files. Else this won't work as intended

Comment: Yes ,you need to add these permissions in Manifest.

Comment: @AnkurJain It should be merged by manifest merger. They should be in the analytics sdk. I don't know its Android Studio issue or manifest merger or sdk

Comment: No, you need to add these permissions in your app manifest. They are not included in analytics manifest.

Comment: @AnkurJain I don't think so. All sdks includes the permissions and are merged by the manifest merger.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @qbix 2.2.1 latest

Comment: I don't see the warning with version 2.2.2, although I doubt it's just a version issue.

Comment: @qbix I chcecked today it was the latest. Sorry. I am not currently in front of laptop. So it should be 2.2.2 (latest)

Comment: @qbix I confirm its 2.2.2.

Comment: Maybe an experiment will produce some clues. Use the Android Studio New Project wizard to create a simple project: File > New > New Project.  The created project will have the default settings and build configuration.  Add the call to `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)` in the `onCreate()` method of the main activity. If you don't see the lint warning, compare your app settings and configuration with the test app.

Comment: @qbix I have created a test project and tried doing the same as you mentioned.  I got the same error again. No luck.

Comment: Sorry--I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: @qbix Thanks for helping :) However, suddenly It disappeared after I modified by gradle.properties file. It was like I wasn't even doing anything and suddenly the red underline gone! Finally!

Answer (score 15):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

to your Manifest file

Android Studio doesn't look in imported lib's manifests. It's just an IDE error. You can disable the inspection

Comment: I can see these in the merged manifest file. I can also see that these 2 permissions are injected by firebase-analytics:9.8.0 manifest

Comment: Updated question with the screenshot

Comment: AndroidStudio doesn't look in imported lib's manifests. It's just an IDE error. You can disable the inspection